# display image from db in image control, alongside other asp.net controls

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, vb.net, image

```
imageTest table
---------------
imgName ( varchar )
contentType ( varchar )
data ( varbinary(max) )


<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />

</div>
</form>
```

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.IO

Partial Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim strCon As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString1").ConnectionString
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(strCon)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    Dim strSelect As String = "SELECT * FROM [imageTest] WHERE [id] = 1"
    cmd.CommandText = strSelect
    con.Open()
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader() 'must be after con.open()

    If (reader.Read()) Then 'must include for reader

        Label1.Text = reader(0).ToString

        Label2.Text = reader(1).ToString()

        reader.Close()

        con.Close()

    End If

End Sub
End Class
```

Database is SQL Server. The image, and not the image path, is stored as `varbinary(max)` in the db.

**How do I display a image from the db, alongside other controls such as `labels` and `textboxes` whose content are also retrieve from the db?**

I have seen and try a number of tutorials but they either in `C#`, or doesn't work, or show you how to display an image only, or display the image in a `gridview`.

Sample codes are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

**first you have to create image folder in our solution
after that writ this method**

```
public static int imageupload(string imagename,string imagepath)
        {

        var value = 0;
        try
        {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ToString());
        //Open the database connection
        con.Open();
        //Query to insert images path and name into database
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into imagetable(imagename,image) values(@imagename,@image)", con);
        //Passing parameters to query
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imagename",imagename);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", imagepath);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        value = 1;
        //Close dbconnection
        con.Close();
         }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(fileuploadimages1.PostedFile.FileName);
        fileuploadimages1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Images/" + filename));
        int a = testapp.imageupload(TextBox1.Text, "Images/" + filename);

        if(a==1)
        {
            Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('saved secussfully')</script>");
            Response.Redirect("home.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('error whie saving image')</script>");
        }

    }
```